# Error when installing Oracle 11.2.0.3 in Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bits

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, windows

I downloaded Oracle 11.2.0.3 installer:

p10404530_112030_MSWIN-x86-64_1of7.zip
p10404530_112030_MSWIN-x86-64_2of7.zip
p10404530_112030_MSWIN-x86-64_3of7.zip
p10404530_112030_MSWIN-x86-64_4of7.zip
p10404530_112030_MSWIN-x86-64_5of7.zip
p10404530_112030_MSWIN-x86-64_6of7.zip
p10404530_112030_MSWIN-x86-64_7of7.zip

Then I unzipped them in same server on path:
C:\Software\Oracle 11.2.0.3 64 bits\oracle\

As an administrator user and without UAC in Windows, when trying to install Oracle software (not database) I get error which is attached in image file.

[image]

Previously I installed Oracle 11.2.0.1 software which I uninstalled before.

Does anyone got a similar error once? What to do in order to install Oracle 11.2.0.3 software?

Comment: For this sort of very specific version-of-software related problems, I would ask on the software vendor's forum first. The chance that you'll find someone who has encountered the same problem is so much higher there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you uncompressed each zip file into its own folder in C:\Software\Oracle 11.2.0.3 64 bits\oracle\ or into the same folder there?  Almost every reference I can find indicates that this problem is caused by the files not being extracted into the same folder.

http://shethedba.wordpress.com/2009/02/02/11g-installation-error-message-file-not-found-wfmlrsvcappear/
http://www.oraerp.com/Thread-WFMLRSVCApp-ear-file-missing-11g-Installation
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=937887
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547101/wfmlrsvcapp-ear-file-not-found
http://lucatarrini.net/?p=230

If you have access to My Oracle Support, there is an article covering this topic - [468771.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/ui/km/SearchDocDisplay.jspx?_afrLoop=375688342719488&recommended=true&type=DOCUMENT&id=468771.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=847dq6q9o_108).

Comment: Thanks, that was my mistake. I unzipped only first zip file, assuming it will unzip automatically the rest of them. I should unzip each one in same destination folder.